# How to add properties to MGLAnnotation in Mapbox for iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, mapbox

How can I add a custom property such as 'Job' or 'Level' etc?

Currently builtins only allow for Title, Description, and Location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subclass `MGLAnnotation` and add custom properties, as following:

```
class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MGLAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    // Custom properties
    var job: Job?
    var level: Level?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }
}
```